# xlwings VBA RunPython is failing to generate logfile

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I am trying to get a VBA macro to call a python program (using xlwings), which will create a logfile as it runs, among its other objectives.

I have the following python function (It creates a basic logfile and writes 1 line to it):

```py
def VBA_log_test(log_value):
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='Prime_Portal.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG, filemode='w')
    
    # Print out input array for debugging purposes
    logging.debug('Input Array:\n' + str(log_value))
```

Here is the VBA macro I'm running, but it does not generate (or update) the logfile.

```
Sub Test_Python_Logfile()
    Debug.Print "Macro Test Started"
    
    Dim python_input As String
    ' python_input = "import testing2; testing2.VBA_log_test('VBA TEST')"
    python_input = "import testing2" & vbNewLine & "testing2.VBA_log_test('VBA TEST')"
    
    Debug.Print "Python Command = " & python_input
    RunPython python_input
    
    Debug.Print "Macro Test Completed"
End Sub
```

Additional Info:

- Both files are in the same directory
- The python code works successfully when called directly

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    VBA_log_test('python test 2')
    # ^^^ This works just fine.
```

- The code also works fine when called from another python file. It is only failing to create the logfile when called from VBA using xlwings and "RunPython"

Comment: Your script only has the logfile name - have you tried supplying a full path?  Your python might behave differently depending on exactly how it's run (directly vs xlwings) - potentially the current directory will be different.

Comment: Agree with @Tim Williams. I tried this and it worked. I changed `logging.basicConfig(filename='Prime_Portal.log', encoding...` to `logging.basicConfig(filename='C:/Temp/Prime_Portal.log', encoding...` The log file was put in the Python environment directory otherwise. And changed 'python_input' in the VBA  code to `python_input = "import " & mymodule & ";" & mymodule & ".VBA_log_test('VBA TEST')"` since my directory naming is different. `mymodule` being taken from the example. Running the macro from Excel produced 'Prime_Portal.log' in 'C:\temp' with the text `DEBUG:root:Input Array: VBA TEST`

Comment: Thank you guys. Using the full path made it work correctly.